# jquery file upload Error Not Found

Tags: codeigniter, jquery-file-upload

I am using jquery file upload with the Codeignitor . I copied the working code and place it in Codeignitor . When i try to upload the file i keep getting this meessage

```
Error Not Found
```

I check on internet and its says path issue where as i can access the file with that path 
in codeignitor my form has this value for action

```
<form id="fileupload" action="<?php echo base_url()?>public/assets/jquery-file-upload/server/php/index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and in firebug i can see the full path in the action attribute .

Comment: Do you use rewrite rules to strip the index.php from you codeigniter path? If so make sure you add an exception for this path.

Comment: That's a rather weird path. The action should point to a controller method, not a file. Which method are you using?

Comment: @Crowlix agree with u i thought through that i can do that , now i putten the controller but i am still getting same error .

Comment: this is not working for me https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/jQuery-File-Upload-6.5-with-CodeIgniter-2.1

Comment: Try browsing to the upload method to see if you have any syntax errors

Comment: just near to solve , now i am getting this error
[{"error":"The upload path does not appear to be valid."}]

Comment: The Upload controller have this
             //Set relative Path with CI Constant
                $this->setPath_img_upload_folder(base_url() . "assets/img/");
                $this->setPath_img_thumb_upload_folder(base_url() . "assets/img/thumbnails/");

                //Delete img url
                $this->setDelete_img_url(base_url() . 'admin/deleteImage/');

                //Set url img with Base_url()
                $this->setPath_url_img_upload_folder(base_url() . "assets/img/");
                $this->setPath_url_img_thumb_upload_folder(base_url() . "assets/img/thumbnails/");

Comment: even i putt the hardcode path it says me same error